# Compilation Error when creating WAR with maven

Tags: eclipse, web-services, maven, pom.xml, xml-rpc

I am trying to create a WAR file with maven within Eclipse and im getting the following errors

[ERROR]/InformationMethods.java:[6,32] package org.apache.xmlrpc.client does not exist
[ERROR]/InformationMethods.java:[7,32] package org.apache.xmlrpc.client does not exist
[ERROR] /InformationMethods.java:[10,25] package org.apache.xmlrpc does not exist
[ERROR]/InformationMethods.java:[11,32] package org.apache.xmlrpc.client does not exist

Here are the dependencies of my POM.xml

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>validateVoucher</groupId>
 <artifactId>validateVoucher</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>test</name>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
   <dependencies>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
<artifactId>xmlrpc</artifactId>
<version>3.1.3</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.util</groupId>
<artifactId>ws-commons-util</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>xerces</groupId>
<artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
<version>1.10</version>
 </dependency>

   <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
<version>2.6.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<version>2.6.2</version>
 </dependency>  
      </dependencies>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

EDIT: 
[ERROR] /PersonInformationMethods.java:[16,9] cannot find symbol 
  symbol:   class XmlRpcClient
  location: class PersonInformationMethods

[ERROR] /PersonInformationMethods.java:[16,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XmlRpcClient
  location: class PersonInformationMethods

[ERROR] /PersonInformationMethods.java:[97,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XmlRpcException
  location: class PersonInformationMethods

[ERROR] /PersonInformationMethods.java:[108,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XmlRpcException
  location: class PersonInformationMethods

[ERROR] /PersonInformationMethods.java:[117,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XmlRpcClientConfigImpl
  location: class PersonInformationMethods

[ERROR] /PersonInformationMethods.java:[117,53] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XmlRpcClientConfigImpl
  location: class PersonInformationMethods

[ERROR] /PersonInformationMethods.java:[129,20] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory
  location: class PersonInformationMethods

EDIT:
Thanks for your help guys, I cant accept two answers but I did exactly what both of you said. I can only upvote the answers and mark one as correct.

Comment: Please post whole error message. Also please correct your dependencies and remove duplications.

Comment: Think I've removed all the duplicates.. That is the only other thing in the output console of eclipse

Comment: Do you have 'maven-war-plugin'  in build section of you pom.xml file?

Comment: Sorry, I do.. Ill update my question with the entire pom file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are not missing any of these dependencies:

- commons-logging.jar
- ws-commons-util.jar
- xmlrpc-client.jar
- xmlrpc-common.jar
- xmlrpc-server.jar

Comment: Thank you man.. I went through your list and added them.. Finally got my War file.. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks for thumbs up :) Good luck

Comment: No problem.. I did both but after going through your list and checking my dependencies, I could finally build my war file. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should correct your pom.xml. It contains `<dependencies>` tag inside build/plugins/plugin. Dependencies have to be declared directly in main element (inside `<project>`).

`XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory` and other classes that you are using are coming from `xmlrpc-client`, as it can be found in [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cc%3A%22XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory%22). So you should remove your dependency to `xmlrpc` and instead use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I did what you said and also went through the list Deepankar sent and it finally worked and I have my war file. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the jar files and folder of the xmlrpc from the maven repository and try to build again, with update snapshots option checked. Some time the jar files will not be downloaded completely